# Proof of $ g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-c^2$ in GR

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

The differential proper time $d\tau$ is defined by

$$
    c^2 d\tau^2 = -g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu \otimes dx^\nu
$$

So i believe we can think of $d\tau^2$ as 
$$
    d\tau^2 = -\frac{1}{c^2}ds^2
$$
where $ds^2$ is the inner product.

I've read that 
\begin{equation}
    g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-c^2
\end{equation}
How can I (rigorously) derive this last equation from the first? Is there a way? Physics texts say it is, but I have not seen it done (apart from obviously not acceptable "proofs" that simply "divide" the first equation by $d\tau^2$ on both sides).

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a thing that can be derived.  The core idea is that each of the $x^{\mu}$ is a function of $\tau$.  If the above equation isn't satisfied, we will have:

$$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau} = -g(\tau)$$

though, we are always free to replace $\tau$ with some (piecewise invertible) function $s = f(\tau)$, so that we have $x^{\mu}(\tau) = x^{\mu}(f^{-1}(s))$ and then, we will have

$$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{ds}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{ds}\left(\frac{df}{d\tau}\right)^2 = -g(\tau)$$

and, we can then just solve the equation so that it solves

$$\frac{df}{d\tau} = \sqrt{g(\tau)}$$

formally, we are choosing the arc length subtended by the curve as its parameter, which, in general relativity, we interpret as the proper distance along the curve.

Comment: I agree with what you have written but I would like to point out a tangentially connected interesting fact: We mostly don't use any piecewise invertible function of the proper time to parametrize the curve. We only use the affine functions so that the geodesic equation is formally preserved.